# How do I align an inflated custom view with the rest of the menu items in Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I don't really know how to put this but all I want is a toolbar (action bar) like the WhatsApp style below.

[image: The style I want]

[image: The style I have managed to develop so far]

Meanwhile, I used the Android toolbar and inflated a custom view (which holds the cart button) and added it using the *setCustomView()* method. I tried tweaking the *textSize* attribute of the *TextView* but even the most reasonable size doesn't align the *TextView* with the rest of the *Toolbar* menu items. Any help on how to do this? Or is there a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly I suggest a different approach, you can set toolbar as a SupportActionBar and add your custom icons as you would do in a normal actionBar

1. Set your toolbar as SupportActionBar

ex.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

2. Create a menu file as you would do to a normal actionBar

ex.

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action1"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="CUSTOM TITTLE"
        android:icon="@drawable/custom_icon1"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action2"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
         android:title="CUSTOM TITTLE"
        android:icon="@drawable/custom_icon2"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />

   </menu>
```

3. Finally use onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected to finish to setup.

ex.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_menu, menu);

    .....

    return true;
}

 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_custom_view:

            .....Your code.....

            break;
        case android.R.id.action_custom_view2:

             .....Your code.....

            break;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: Yeah I used your method for the search icon but since I don't have a cart icon png image (or any other format) I decided to use a font icon but after doing that, I came up with that bar above. Any ideas on how to align both the custom view child and the menu children such that they all display on a straight line OR do I have to get a PNG image icon before I can get this done?

Comment: Okay, I got it. 
Toolbar is a ViewGroup(Layout) so you could give up the suggestion I gave above and set all the views on the xml as you would do with a ViewGroup and align it as you want and set the behaviors manually on the java code or you could get the png image.

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice bro, I now have the toolbar I want✌